# Does CC.NET allow linking to premade .html instead of .xsl

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Does CC.NET allow for you to link to premade .html files on the plugin bar on the left?

I know it allows for you to link via XSL, but when I use the XSL for a certain plugin it does not display correctly.  But the program can make a .html file itself so i was wondering if i could have it make one then link to it.

I know TeamCity has the capabilities to do this I was just wondering if CC.NET had this too.

And I know about the external links ability, but I want to link to it from the bar on the left, not the main build screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in your `webdashboard\templates` folder.  In there are all the templates the server uses.  I think you probably could edit `ProjectSideBar.vm` and add a normal `<a href="">xxx</a>` and use your file name and possibly one of the variables used in the file, something like:

```
<tr><td><a href="$projectName\outputFile.htm">Your File Ouput</a></td></tr>
```

I don't know if $projectName exists, but look in the other .vm files and you should be able to find something.

It should work, although I can't check myself at the moment.

Comment: BTW: .vm files are NVelocity template files

Answer (score 1):

Look at the trunk on sourceforge, I just read that in 1.5 is going to be an html plugin on the dashboard for displaying html output...

Comment: me likey... any idea on the release date besides '2009'

Comment: well the source for 1.5 is the trunk, you might see if it has been implemented already. Other than looking I'd have no way to know..

Answer (score 0):

The Html Report Plugin is what you want to use - it's available starting with release 1.5 as Alex mentioned: http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/HtmlReportPlugin

**EDIT**: I've spent a couple of days with the Html Report Plugin and unfortunately it looks like it has too many bugs to be useful.  See my issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909271/relative-links-not-working-in-cruisecontrol-net-htmlreportplugin) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ccnet-user/XQuJHHCiPnE%5B1-25%5D).